# Angular2: Trigger function of a childcomponent after user is logged in

Tags: function, angular, triggers, components

I have the appcomponent and in the HTML of the appcomponent I Load the childcomponent of my menu.

I have a function in my menucomponent. I want it to be triggered after a user has logged in. Because then I want to do a http call to get a picture of the user and display it on the menu.

```
<app-menu></app-menu>
<div class="container">
<router-outlet>/*HERE IS WHERE THE USER GETS LOGGED IN*/</router-outlet>
</div>
```

I use routing to load in my logincomponent so I can`t use the click event to trigger the function in the menucomponent.

Does someone have any suggestions how to fix this?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it can helps, I use Subject and Subscription in a main Service to listen to a user's login/logout.

**main.service.ts**

```
public loginState: boolean;
public loginStateOnChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>(); // listen to the variable isLogin

isLogin(): boolean{ return this.loginState; }
setLogin(value: boolean): void{ this.loginState = value; }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
_loginSubscription: any;

constructor(mainService: MainService) {
    this.mainService = mainService;
    this._loginSubscription = this.mainService.loginStateOnChange.subscribe((value) => { this.onChangeLogin(); });
}

onChangeLogin(){
// this may be your trigger
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
login() {
    (...)
    this.mainService.setLogin(true);
    this.mainService.loginStateOnChange.next(this.mainService.isLogin());
}

logout(){
    this.mainService.setLogin(false);
    this.mainService.loginStateOnChange.next(this.mainService.isLogin());
}
```

Hope it will help you. Do not hesitate if you need more informations ?

Comment: There is some code also in my Menu.component. does this component gets triggered because of the app.component or how can I see this?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I would rather try to add another subscription in your Menu.component. I think each component listening to a login's change need to have a subscribe() function. Or maybe you could try to have a main component with this subscription and the two components you need to get triggered extends for this main component.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case it would make sense using a service, since it's not a parent-child relationship.

Example of using a service:

Service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class CommunicateService {

  // source of change
  private newStringSource = new Subject<string>();

  // observable
  public stringCreated = this.newStringSource.asObservable();

  public sendNewString(newString: string): void {
    // broadcasts the new data to every listener
    this.newStringSource.next(newString);
  }
}
```

App component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CommunicateService} from './communicate.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>
    {{title}}
    <app-child></app-child>
  </h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app works!';


  constructor(private communicateService: CommunicateService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.communicateService.stringCreated.subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
}
```

Child with a button trigger as an example. This would be the component triggering the event after the user has logged in.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CommunicateService} from '../communicate.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<p>
    child works!
    <button (click)="onClick()"> Click me </button>
  </p>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {

  constructor(private communicateService: CommunicateService) {
  }

  onClick() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      this.communicateService.sendNewString(`i is ${i}`); // string interpolation
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @LLL this is not exactly what i mean when the click on the childcomponent happends like you demonstrated an other componenents function has to be triggered

Comment: Well do it through the service like in my example. Inject the service to both components you want to communication and register the listener to the one listening to it and push changes from the other one. Or I'm misunderstanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: its a good solution Unfortunately the other solution was also oke!